# Hosting fasttext model (.bin) in redis

Tags: python-3.x, redis, user-agent, text-classification, fasttext

I have trained a text classification model (for classifying User Agent strings) and generated a bin file. I'm looking to host the model (preferably Redis) but haven't found any articles in relevance. The model will need to classify millions of requests per second, if not more and would need to be hosted in multiple server instances. So I'm looking to create an efficient solution for hosting the model, either through Redis or any other scalable way.

TIA!

Comment: Are you using the Facebook FastText code, and the `-supervised` FastText mode?

Comment: actually this is what i am searching today :) if you find a elegant solution, dont forget to write here.

Comment: @gojomo yes, I have trained a supervised model and generated a model file (.bin) which needs to be accessed-from/deployed-to multiple servers to classify the User Agents of incoming requests. So I am searching for a solution to possibly host the model file on redis.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Facebook Research's own released FastText code is the only code supporting `-supervised` model training, saving, & deployment.

So you'll likely need to distribute your trained model `.bin` to multiple servers, then use the Facebook code, wrapped in some sort of service process, to answer queries.

It's hard to imagine any role for Redis, as the underlying model weights in the Facebook save-format, & as Facebook code loads into main memory, are already in a raw, compact, complete format.

It's not something that the indirection of as added key-value/database layer would improve – the whole model is needed, and in the Facebook code's expected raw format, for the classification operations to work. That is, there's nothing to be gained by parceling that model out in smaller pieces, perhaps from remote replicas, or adapting the classification code to access the model through any extra retrieval-API. But adding such indirection might slow or complicate things.

However, in practice aren't there a small number of very-common `User-Agent` strings, then a long tail of rarer ones? So of the "millions of requests per second", 99% are likely to be from the same set of a few dozen (or few hundred) strings, for which the classifications can be cached - not requiring any consultation of the underlying FastText model?

In such a case, you might only need one service doing the full FastText-classification, but a large number of simple caches in front of that service, each servicing most requests from a cached prior answer.